# Create Snowpipe Copy into using a file form a stage fails

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I try to load the data below from a stage file it fails with invalid date, is there a way to resolve this issue? Without changing the source file.

I am trying to setup a Snowpipe

Orig_Int_Date
04-21-2020

```
create or replace file format Ally_format
    type = csv
    field_delimiter = '|'
    skip_header = 1
    empty_field_as_null = true
    REPLACE_INVALID_CHARACTERS = TRUE 
    DATE_FORMAT = '<MM-DD-YYYY>'
    EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE;**

Copy into NAM_FIN_DB.FIN_PUBLIC.ALLY
    from  @NAM_FIN_DB.PUBLIC.FP_FINANCE 
    file_format = Ally_format
    pattern='ALLY.*';**
```

Comment: Presumably there is data somewhere in your source file that doesn't match the format you've defined. I would suggest you try loading it into something like Excel and seeing if you can spot the issue

Comment: It fails with the date I provided, so a file with just 04-21-2021 will not load. Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your date format line should be:

```
DATE_FORMAT = 'MM-DD-YYYY'
```

not

```
DATE_FORMAT = '<MM-DD-YYYY>'
```